# Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.slf4j.Logger to org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, logging, log4j

i configure my environment in eclipse Mars but i got an error with the log4j. I use spring 4 and maven as dependency manager. Hier some part of code:

Eclipse show me an error on this line, the second part after the equals:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyConfiguration.class);
```

The error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.slf4j.Logger to org.apache.log4j.Logger
```

My propertyConfiguration is into the com.myapp.bootstrap and the xml file into src/main/resources.

my log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="defaultAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.myapp" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="defaultAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="defaultAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And someone any ideas?

Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your imports. Sometimes Eclipse chooses the import org.slf4j.Logger instead of org.apache.log4j.Logger.

Use combination of either

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

or

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Priority;
```

or

Slf4j  according to your library

Comment: More likely a user error, than "Eclipse screws up". When fixing imports, Eclipse shows a list of choices, and the *user* makes the wrong choice, likely by being too fast and not reading the options provided.

Comment: Pretty sure I've actually had it automatically select that one on me, without giving me options, but it's been a while so maybe I'm misremembering.

Answer (score 3):

For me one of my spring project intellij was the culprit, it was actually auto importing

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

I had to update import manually with below

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Spring boot IntelliJ and this fixed the error

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.*;
```